# Как сделать отступ?

Tags: html, css

```
<li>
    <img/>
    <div class="desc">
        <span class="desc_img">Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </span>
    </div>
</li>


.desc_services  { display: block; margin-top: -20px; width: 100%; height: 60px;}
.desc_img{line-height: 20px; text-align:left;text-transform:uppercase;overflow:hidden;padding:2px 0;}
```

Сейчас есть такой отступ:

[image]

Возможно ли сделать отступ по бокам? Если делать в спане, то отступ идет от первого и последнего слова. А нужно, чтобы еще перед второй и третьей строчкой сделался отступ в 3 пикс :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо в `desc_services` задайте `padding`, либо `desc_img` превратите в блочный элемент (`display: block/inline-block;`).

Зависит от остальных требований - вариантов решения много :)

Comment: В desc_services не пойдет он сделать отсуп и desc_img сместится. нужно что бы бэкграунд был черный слева и справа. А если сделать desc_img блочным то он будет черный квадрат, а нужно что бы только по тексту был черный бэкграунд